# How to reset darktable

Tags: darktable

I need a way of reseting darktable to its factory settings.

With shotwell it is simply a case of deleting the home directory for shotwell, but there doesn't appear to be one for DT under the Darktable name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe that the config files for darktable are under ~/.config/darktable.  Usually, deleting the config files will cause them to be regenerated at the next startup.  Any changes you made to the default settings will be lost.

Before deleting your config files, though, delete just the Darktable library file (~/.config/darktable/library.db).  This is where Darktable saves information about the images you've imported.  After you delete the library file, Darktable won't know anything about your image collection (and should stop crashing).  You'll have to re-import the photos you want to work with, but happily, the library file is mostly just a cache that speeds up various operations within Darktable.  Darktable saves all important image metadata (including tags, edit history, etc.) in XMP "sidecar" files alongside the images themselves.  Hopefully, all you'll lose is a bit of time.

*Always* make a backup of any files you intend to experiment with.

Comment: "library file is mostly just a cache" Yes and no. In practice, deleting the library will re-import from XMP if present. But beware of losing work in some cases. For details see https://www.mail-archive.com/darktable-user@lists.darktable.org/msg01929.html https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/ch02s02s07.html.php
For an extended lecture, see https://www.mail-archive.com/darktable-user@lists.darktable.org/msg01931.html